# Lagom - Could not find Cassandra contact points, due to: access denied

Tags: scala, lagom

Could not find Cassandra contact points, due to: Access Denied.
Your credentials could not be authenticated. Credentials are missing. Not sure how to fix this.

I am trying to run the lagom sample online-auction-scala.

Comment: Is that standard documentation example you are trying to run? https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/scala/IntroGetStarted.html

Comment: yes. I am trying the example from standard documentation

Answer (score 0):

Is your configuration routing localhost requests through a proxy? Can you disable that so that localhost requests stay local?

I don't know how your machine/proxy is configured, so I'm not sure what to do specifically. You might need to set the "http.nonProxyHosts" system property when launching sbt.

These links might be helpful:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html
- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setup-Notes.html#HTTP%2FHTTPS%2FFTP+Proxy
- http://objects-and-lambdas.com/learning-play-framework-2.html